# how to create a temp file inside of Android service

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an AIDL interface in which there is a method that needs to create a temporary file.  When implementing this method in a class that derives from the `MyService.Stub` class, I have the following code:

```
class ServiceImplementation extends DmServiceInterface.Stub {
   // ...

   @Override
   public void uploadResource(ParcelFileDescriptor pipe) {
      //...

      File tmpDir = context.getCacheDir();
      Log.d(TAG, String.format("Temp dir: %s", tmpDir));

      File uploadFile = File.createTempFile("dm_", ".bin", tmpDir);
      Log.i(TAG, String.format("Setting up upload file at %s", uploadFile.getAbsolutePath()));

      //...
   }

   //...

}
```

where the `context` reference is saved in the onCreate() callback of the corresponding service instance:

```
public class CcService extends Service {
    private Context context;

    // ...

    public void onCreate() {
       context = getApplicationContext();
       //...
    }
}
```

when I run the code under the emulator, I get the following:

```
D/dm.service: temp dir: null
W/ContextImpl: Unable to create files subdir /data/user/0/com.dm.ccserver/cache
E/dm.service: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1004)
W/System.err:     at com.dm.ccserver.ServiceImplementation.uploadResource(ServiceImplementation.java:69)
W/System.err:     at com.dm.ccserver.DmServiceInterface$Stub.onTransact(DmServiceInterface.java:73)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

1. Why does `getCacheDir()` return `null`?
2. Despite (1), the call to createTempFile() still seems to be defaulting to the correct directory.  Why am I getting an IOException, though?

The cache directory does exist:

```
  root@generic_x86:/ # ls -ld /data/user/0/com.dm.ccserver/cache
  drwxrwx--x u0_a66   u0_a66            2016-11-22 17:14 cache
```

Comment: You do not need Application context here. Have you tried just using this.getCacheDir() ?

Comment: I have tried a version where `this` refers to the service class instance and got the same error.